# DataTables selected rows data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've got datatables set up nicely and with the select extension - I have this code for when someone uses a "report" and it loads another page using some cell content from the table to pass to the report. That works fine, however - I need to be able to pass a `data-element` of each `<tr>` of the table instead of the row data...

This is my current code:

```
var table = $('#table_search_project').DataTable();

//then re-run the code to get the selected rows
var id_list = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
    return item[1]
});
```

So you can see, I used to use `item[1]` to return, but I really want to be able to get the `<tr>` object so I can retrieve the `data-something-id` property (but I don't want to show it - hence the issue)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I worked it out. Too hasty to ask in SO!

I used this instead:

```
var id_list = $.map(table.rows('.selected').nodes(), function (item) {
    return $(item).data("entity-id");
});
```

The `nodes()` collection sends me back the `<tr>` elements instead of the data. Exactly what I wanted. Found the information here:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().node()

Comment: Awesome, very useful. Sometimes it's pretty tricky to find exactly how to use the pretty complex data model of DT, nodse(), node(), $(this), data() etc... This was the right combination!

Comment: Tried this but finally had to change it the last line to target attr to get it to work   return $(item).attr("data-id"). Still very useful

Comment: `.data()` has been in jQuery since 1.2.3 - what version are you running?